# Why printf function print the result in order when the order of number is not corresponding to the format?

Tags: c, printf, format-specifiers

When I ran the following code:

```
printf("%d %f %d %d %f\n", 1.2 , 3000, 2.5, 400, 500);
```

What I thought was the answer might be some meaningless number, but the result was actually:

```
3000 1.200000 400 500 2.500000
```

which is just the same number and in the same format as my input.

It was so meaningful that I can't persuade myself ignoring it.

Could someone tell me the reason? I would be very grateful.

p.s. I'm using Clion as my IDE.

Comment: `1.2` is neither `int` nor  `float` but `double`. So your data is not matching the format string rendering undefined behavior.

Comment: UB͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏

Comment: It's UB, but a plausible explanation is that your `printf` library function is expecting the parameters corresponding to `%d` and `%f` to have been placed in completely different sets of registers. This is true for Linux AMD64 calling convention.

Comment: Clion does not matter. What is relevant is your *compiler* (pedantically your implementation of C) which is run by your IDE, probably some [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/). But you still have UB. BTW you should enable all warnings & debug info, e.g. compile with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because - it is pointless to answer people who: 1. intentionally abuse the language / library functions 2. Did not bother to read even the shortest C tutorial to understand the simplest basic topics.

Comment: It's a peculiar artefact of the the calling conventions (ABI) on this particular system.  It is 100% undependable.  You invoked undefined behaviour; you get what you get, and you were mostly unlucky that it seemed to make some sort of perverted sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a guess: On your ABI floating point arguments are passed via the FPU stack, integers through the CPU-stack. So when printf pulls the arguments, it pulls `%f`s from the FPU stack and pops `%d`s off the CPU-stack. If I am right, `printf("%d %d %d ***** %f %f\n", 1.2 , 2.5,     3000, 400, 500);` should work for you too. So the mixup between floats and others (%d, %s & Co) will be recovered for you, the order is preserved. Needless to add: all this is >150% UB.

Comment: Since now this answer is accepted, can you please move the last line to the beginning to emphasize the statement? The question lacks the implementation details, so it might confuse others .

Answer (score 7):

Supplying inappropriate type for a given format specifier is [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), you can never "justify" the result. It *may* seem to work fine, but you never know, internally it may be transferring all your money to some other account!!

Quoting `C11`, chapter §7.21.6.1, P9

> [...] If any argument is
>   not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is
>   undefined.

In your case,

- `%d` expects `int`, you supplied `double` (literal `1.2` is a `double`)
- `%f` expects a `double`, you supplied an `int`.

So, you cause UB. **Just don't do it.**